# WCF. Create generic Servicecontract. Fill from client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, generics, servicecontract

Maybe it is duplicate, but I couldn't succeed to find needed answer.

Actually I am trying to build generic wrapper in order to work with Entity/L2Sql via wcf. So on the server side:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class MyDbContext<TTable> : IMyDbContext<TTable> where TTable:class 
{  
    private readonly DataContext _dbContext;
    private readonly Table<Device> _table;

    public MyDbContext()
    {
        _dbContext = new WCF_DataContext(connection);
        _table = _dbContext.GetTable<TTable>();
    }

    public void InsertOnSubmit(TTable table)
    {
        _table.InsertOnSubmit(table);
    }
    ...and the same stuff further...
}
```

and on the client side I am using like this

```
var client = new ServiceRef.MyDbContextClient<ServiceRef.PersonTable>();
client.GetData(); client.insertOnSubmit(); ...other stuff...
```

I understand what WCF created for universal stuff, different languages, and its natural to forbid straight T, but maybe there is a way to aproach this with some attributes or descriptions (like where T:DataContractAttribute, but this is invalid).

Or maybe I started to think wrong way=)

For some viewmodels I need one DbContext per viewmodel, instead of short using (..dbcontext..)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use known type atribute on your contract.

You can find out more information here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope it helps.